# Change TTY resolution on Fedora

Tags: fedora, tty, i3, resolution, rxvt

I'm using Fedora 25 on ASUS laptop connected to the LG external monitor.
The monitor (unlike the laptop's screen itself) doesn't show TTY full screen, while it's okay with the GUI (that's i3wm or Gnome) after startx command. It might be because the laptops resolution (1366x768) is lower than the monitors, and CLI unlike GUI doesn't resolve it automatically.

One reason why I want to use TTY is because sometimes the colors (esp. of CMus and Ranger) mess up on the urxvt terminal in GUI.

How can I make the TTY full screen in the ~1400x1050 monitor?